# Azure ASR Encryption in failback

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

When we replicate data from onprem to azure using ASR it will encrypt the data while transit and rest, but will it encrypt in fail back from Azure to on-prem?

Answer (score 0):

It will, else it would make no sense to use it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-failback

this doesnt mention anything about manual steps to decrypt vms during failback